# HTML `img` tag can't display as image in object jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have data from "sugestion" var like this, this after I conevert the object "suggestion" to string.

```
{"value":"<img src=\"http://localhost/erp/assets/images/product/123.jpg\"> 123123123 t-shirt","data":"ABC098765"}
```

But `<img src="\"http://localhost/erp/assets/images/product/123.jpg\">` can't display as image, the image tag only display as text after append to

this is the ouput display.

```
html += '<div class="' + className + '" data-index="' + i + '">' + formatResult(suggestion, value, i) + '</div>';
```

The complite script

```
    $.each(that.suggestions, function (i, suggestion) {
        if (groupBy){
            html += formatGroup(suggestion, value, i);
        }
        html += '<div class="' + className + '" data-index="' + i + '">' + formatResult(suggestion, value, i) + '</div>';
    });
```

the format result

```
Autocomplete.formatResult = function (suggestion, currentValue) {
        // Do not replace anything if there current value is empty
        if (!currentValue) {
            return suggestion.value;
        }

        var pattern = '(' + utils.escapeRegExChars(currentValue) + ')';

        return suggestion.value
            .replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'gi'), '<strong>$1<\/strong>')
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/&lt;(\/?strong)&gt;/g, '<$1>');
    };
```

How to make the image tag as image when the output display?

Thank you

Comment: Need `formatResult` function code to debug.

Comment: Where you add `html` to your DOM? How does the `formatResult` look like?

Comment: @Sasikumar I've shown above

Comment: @mplungjan yes i have shown againt in above

Comment: console.log the suggestion.value before returning it? You likely do not convert the \"

Comment: @mplungjan this the console.log result <img src="http://localhost/erp/assets/images/product/123.jpg"> 123123123 t-shirt

Comment: So the &gt; needs to be fixed and you likely need to use relative path instead of server path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Stripslashes function to strip slash while returning `suggestion.value`. May be because of the extra slashes your image is not displaying properly.

```
function stripslashes (str) {
  return (str + '').replace(/\\(.?)/g, function (s, n1) {
    switch (n1) {
    case '\\':
      return '\\';
    case '0':
      return '\u0000';
    case '':
      return '';
    default:
      return n1;
    }
  });
}
```